# Plane separation axiom

Tags: geometry

> Let $\mathbb{R}^3=\{(x,y,z)\mid x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}\}$. If $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^3$ define $L_{AB}=\{A+t(B-A)\mid t\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Let $Y=\{L_{AB}\mid A,B\in\mathbb{R}^3. \ A\ne B\}.$ If $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^3$ let $d(A,B)=\|A-B\|.$ Prove that this does not satisfy the plane separation axiom (PSA).

PSA is defined as, if for every $l\in P$, where $P$ is a set of points, there are two subsets $H_1$ and $H_2$ of $P$ (called half planes determined by the line $l$) such that:

- $i.$ $P-l=H_1\cup H_2$
- $ii.$ $H_1$ and $H_2$ are disjoint and each is convex
- $iii.$ If $A\in H_1$ and $B\in H_2$ then $\overline{AB}\cap l \ne \emptyset.$

I am not sure how to prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to partition $\mathbb R^3 - L_{AB}$ (i) into two convex sets (ii). The only convex set whose complement in $\mathbb R^3$ is convex as well is a half space. Excluding $L_{AB}$ doesn't change that fact very much, and with a bit of work one should be able to formalize that. So you'll have to consider two half spaces touching in a plane, and if you look at the details you will notice that the plane has to contain $L_{AB}$ and be subdivided as well. But what is important here are the interiors of the half spaces: You will certainly find a point in each so that their connecting line does not cross $L_{AB}$, thus violating (iii).